# Window doesn't show up on tkinter window. It shows up in the Mac menubar instead. How is this fixable?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I want the menu to show up in the tkinter window. Why is it showing up in the Mac menubar. I notice this is a Mac problem as I don't really have this problem with windows.

Picture of the problem:
[image]

Code:

```
# import libraries
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Menu

# window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("NewPlay")
window.geometry('1000x800')
window.minsize(1000, 800) # minimum size user can scale window
window.maxsize(1200, 1000) # maximum size user can scale window

# menu
def menu():
    # menubar
    menuBar = Menu(window)
    window.config(menu=menuBar)

    # creates menu
    user_menu = Menu(menuBar)

    # exit program
    user_menu.add_command(
        label='Exit',
        command=window.destroy
    )

    # search for music
    menuBar.add_cascade(
        label="Search",
        menu=user_menu
    )

# loop window
menu()
window.config(bg="orange") # background color
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Different operating systems will handle a ```Menu``` differently, but this is a ```Menu``` widget's intended purpose. If you want a new window look into a ```Toplevel```

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. That's the only thing I hate about Mac. :(